# Cambiar nombre a botón "Sign in" - Wordpress - Themes

Tags: html, wordpress

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Estoy interesado en cómo cambiar el nombre al botón "**Suscríbete**". He descargado el "Loco translate" para traducir las palabras o frases del tema de **Wordpress** pero no encuentro la frase o cadena de palabras "Sign in".

He visto que está integrado en el **HTML**, al cual no tengo acceso (o no sé cómo podría tenerlo) debido a que es una plantilla, llamada **TechOne**, integrada en Wordpress para crear una tienda online.

**¿Alguna solución para renombrar el botón de "Sign in" a "Suscríbete"?**

Comment: Si esta en el HTML puedes cambiarlo buscando la coincidencia con tu editor. Busca *"Sign in"* en todo el proyecto y encontrarás el lugar donde cambiarlo. Si no aparece, seguramente este en la BD, uno de los problemas de éste tipo de aplicaciones es el uso masivo que hacen del almacenamiento en BD. Haz un volcado a SQL y busca en el fichero para localizar la tabla. No olvides hacer una búsqueda *case-sensitive* y si ésta no funciona volver a intentarlo con *case-insensive*.

Comment: Estoy en Wordpress y he buscado "Sign in" y no me sale ninguna ocurrencia. El botón se llama "Sign in" y con botón derecho sobre él con el "Inspeccionar elemento", también lo he localizado pero nada.

Comment: ¿Has mirado que el botón no sea una imagen? Y si no lo es, ¿no puedes sacar el html del template descargado? ¿Podrías añadir alguna captura para poder verlo mejor?

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con una imagen adjuntada. Captura enviada.

Comment: No soy experto en wordpress, pero no tienes alguna forma de poder descargarte la plantilla, editarlo y resubirla, por ejemplo?

Comment: Basándome en mis conocimientos no, pero ojalá existiera esa forma para poder realizarlo. No encuentro los archivos .html.

Comment: ¿No tienes acceso al servidor FTP donde se encuentran los archivos?

Comment: Si lo tenemos pero no está el html. No hay ningún archivo ".html", son todos los archivos mezclas de html y php con extensión ".php". En cada uno de esos archivos ".php" no lo encuentro. Estaría en el footer.php pero nada...

Comment: Debería de estar... si no es así, no se me ocurre ninguna forma de ayudarte. Tal vez si añades esta información que me has comentado en la pregunta, para añadir más detalles, alguien pueda ayudarte. Ya lo siento.

Comment: Los temas se pueden editar desde: Apariencia -> Editor
En esta página eliges el tema a editar y después la página concreta que tenga ese texto en el HTML. Editas el archivo y "Actualizar archivo".

Comment: Al final no queda claro si tienes un tema de Worpress o un tema particular (la mención de *una plantilla TechOne*  se presta a confusión). En todo caso, hay varias formas de hacer la traducción. Una es usando `Poedit` (en la red hay varios tutoriales, [por ejemplo este](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-translate-a-wordpress-theme/)). Otra forma sería reemplazando ese valor directamente mediante CSS, para ello debes ubicar el CSS que se carga con WP y modificar parte de él. Algunos frameworks como Thesis te permiten tener una sección Custom CSS para eso.

Comment: ¡Buenas! Lo normal es que si es Theme comprado ese código se encuentra insertado en la página footer.php del Theme y allí podrás modificarlo a pelo. ¿Tienes acceso al editar de Wordpress de la plantilla? Saludos.

Comment: El tutorial de traducción ya lo revisé y también he traducido casi todas las frases o palabras, lo que ocurre que al ser un botón no me deja traducirlo. He buscado en TODOS los .php la palabra "Sign in" y no existe. Probaré con Poedit... aunque creo que es similar a "Loco translate".

Comment: He realizado los pasos que me has dicho pero no encuentra la palabra "Sign in" en ningún fichero .php, y tengo elegido el tema a editar.

Comment: Si es comprado, pero lo que ocurre que en el código footer.php de esa página no me sale eso, me aperece lo siguiente: </div>
<?php techone_get_footer();?>
<a href="#" class="backtotop"><?php esc_html_e('Back to top','techone');?><span><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></span></a>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Sólo me aparece ese código que he copiado.

Comment: Acabo de entrar en la web, para poder ayudarte, entiendo que ese caja está en un Widget  ¿Qué plugin estás usando para qué aparezca? Miralo y puede que allí encuentres el código.

Comment: No es ningún plugin. Venía por defecto en el tema descargado. Y lo que quiero -simplemente- es modificar el texto "Sign in", frase que no encuentro en ningún .php

Comment: Mira dentro del Widget ¿Qué es lo que tienes?

Comment: Es un layout del tema ese Widget.

Comment: ¿Has probado a bajarte el theme y buscar esa cadena en todos los archivos con el buscador del Sistema?

Comment: Entonces es un widget como he visto que apuntaban en otras respuestas. Muchos temas llevan los widget ya instalados y ubicados en los sitios convenientes.

Comment: El theme claro que lo tengo, lo tengo en el servidor FTP y tengo acceso a todos los archivos, pero en una búsqueda general no lo he encontrado y con una búsqueda concreta tampoco.

Comment: Espero que cuando resuelva el problema, pueda compartir la solución.

Comment: ¿Cómo hago un volcado a SQL? Sólo tengo los ficheros .php, nada más. En esos ficheros .php no existe ningún div con el id/name "Sign in".

Comment: @omaza1990 ¿puedes acceder a la base de datos mediante phpMyAdmin? Hay tienes la opción, después de seleccionar la BD. Debes 'exportar'. Tienes la opción de volcar toda la BD a un fichero SQL donde hacer búsquedas.

Comment: A la base de datos desde localhost/phpmyadmin no me permite, lo que si tengo son los ficheros .php, pero no tengo ningun fichero BBDD o .sql

Answer (score 0):

Si esta en el HTML puedes cambiarlo buscando la coincidencia con tu editor. Busca *"Sign in"* en todo el proyecto y encontrarás el lugar donde cambiarlo.

Si no aparece, seguramente este en la BD, uno de los problemas de éste tipo de aplicaciones es el uso masivo que hacen del almacenamiento en BD. Haz un volcado a SQL y busca en el fichero para localizar la tabla.

No olvides hacer una búsqueda *case-sensitive* y si ésta no funciona volver a intentarlo con *case-insensive*.

Comment: Estoy en Wordpress y he buscado "Sign in" y no me sale ninguna ocurrencia. El botón se llama "Sign in" y con botón derecho sobre él con el "Inspeccionar elemento", también lo he localizado pero nada.

Comment: ¿Cómo hago un volcado a SQL? Sólo tengo los ficheros .php, nada más. En esos ficheros .php no existe ningún div con el id/name "Sign in".

Comment: @omaza1990 ¿puedes acceder a la base de datos mediante phpMyAdmin? Hay tienes la opción, después de seleccionar la BD. Debes 'exportar'. Tienes la opción de volcar toda la BD a un fichero SQL donde hacer búsquedas.

Comment: A la base de datos desde localhost/phpmyadmin no me permite, lo que si tengo son los ficheros .php, pero no tengo ningun fichero BBDD o .sql